# Deploying to vercel

Tags: node.js, express, create-react-app, vercel

Hello i'm having issues deploying my website/app to vercel. It's a node/express backend and a create-react-app front end.
I should start by saying that localy everything works perfectly.
As for deployment, when vercel builds it, in its build logs appears this line "Warning: Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: [https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings"](https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings%22).

Not only that, when visiting the vercel it appeears 404 not found. (https://note-keeper-node-backend-2gbi1g75b-orlandovsilva.vercel.app/)

Also followed this tutorial (https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/how-to-deploy-a-node-express-app-to-vercel-2aa).

What could the issue be?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

For 404 not found in vercel try to put in Settings->Project Settings->Environment Variables->Add New

Name field => CI
VALUE field => false

This works for me. Resolve 404 problem in vercel deployment.

Verify if you put Root Directory of your project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all what is your vercel.json and paste this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```